# What is the penalty for not respecting GDPR outside EU?

Tags: gdpr

What happens when a newspaper website in USA or in Australia or in Japan does not comply with GDPR?

Can EU punish them in any way?

Comment: An answer to this question (once it receives a substantiated answer) would probably answer your question, too. [In which jurisdictions outside the EU can the GDPR be enforced?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/36663/in-which-jurisdictions-outside-the-eu-can-the-gdpr-be-enforced)